# LALR(1) parser generator for scala

Tags: parsing, scala, lalr

I know that it's possible to use, for example, bison-generated Java files in scala project, but is there any native "grammar to scala" LALR(1) generators?

Comment: Does anyone actually read generated LALR parser code? I haven't seen anything like this, and am not sure there'd be much of a market for it, given that there are mature Java solutions and the generated Scala would probably be just as inscrutable.

Comment: @TravisBrown advantage here is not to read java code, but ability to write semantic actions in Scala.

Comment: But with a little bit of wrapping it should be possible to do that with a Bison-generated Java parser.

Comment: @TravisBrown it is OK for me (if this wrapping doesn't mean using external Scala file), but can you give an example of such wrapping?

Answer (score 1):

Another plug here: [ScalaBison](http://www.cs.uwm.edu/~boyland/scala-bison.html) is close to LALR(1) and lets you use Scala in the actions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really answering the original question, and please excuse the plug, but you may be interested in our [sbt-rats plugin for the sbt tool](http://sbt-rats.googlecode.com). It uses the [Rats! parser generator](http://cs.nyu.edu/rgrimm/xtc/rats-intro.html) for Java, but makes it easier to use from Scala.

Rats! uses parsing expression grammars as its syntax description formalism, not context-free grammars and definitely not LALR(1) grammars. sbt-rats also has a high-level syntax definition language that in most cases means you do not need to write semantic actions to get a syntax tree that represents your input. The plugin will optionally generate case classes for the tree representation and a pretty-printer for the tree structure.